# Two levels of longitudinal data: how to reshape?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape2, multi-level

I have a data set with multiple time points of hippocampal volume for each subject. Each hippocampal volume has a left and right measurement. I now want to compare left and right change longitudinally. I know how to reshape my data for the time points, but I don't know how to add the levels of "side" to it.

So here is my reproducible data set:

```
mydata <- data.frame(SID=sample(1:150,400, replace=TRUE), hippLeft_T1=sample(6000:8000,400,replace=TRUE), hippRight_T1=sample(6000:8000,400,replace=TRUE),hippLeft_T2=sample(6000:8000,400,replace=TRUE), hippRight_T2=sample(6000:8000,400,replace=TRUE),hippLeft_T3=sample(6000:8000,400,replace=TRUE), hippRight_T3=sample(6000:8000,400,replace=TRUE))
```

This is then how I would reshape it longitudinally:

```
long <- reshape(mydata, direction="long", varying=list(c(2,4,6),c(3,5,7)),idvar="SID", timevar="time", v.names=c("HippLeft","HippRight"), times=c("time1","time2","time3"))
```

Should I apply reshape twice to get the levels for left and right in there? Or is there another way to do this? Thanks!

**What I am trying to get is the following:
[image]

Comment: can you post an example of what you're hoping your output data will look like?

Comment: So I just added an example, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a combination of `unite`, `gather`, and `separate` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
long <- mydata %>% unite("times1", hippLeft_T1,hippRight_T1) %>%
                   unite("times2", hippLeft_T2,hippRight_T2) %>%
                   unite("times3", hippLeft_T3,hippRight_T3) %>%
                   gather("times","Hipp",times1:times3) %>%
                   separate(Hipp,c("Left","Right")) %>%
                   gather("Side","Hipp",Left:Right)
```

Notes:

1. First `unite` the left and right columns for each time `T1`, `T2`, and `T3` and name these columns `times1`, `times2`, and `times3`
2. Then, `gather` these three columns naming the key column `times` and the value column `Hipp`
3. `separate` the `Hipp` column into `Left` and `Right`
4. `gather` the `Left` and `Right` columns naming the key column `Side` and the value column `Hipp`

Actually a better way is to reverse the two `gather` operations by first uniting over times:

```
library(tidyr)
long <- mydata %>% unite("Left", hippLeft_T1,hippLeft_T2,hippLeft_T3) %>%
                   unite("Right", hippRight_T1,hippRight_T2,hippRight_T3) %>%
                   gather("Side","Hipp",Left:Right) %>%
                   separate(Hipp,c("times1","times2","times3")) %>%
                   gather("times","Hipp",times1:times3)
```

A third approach using only one call to `gather` is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
long <- mydata %>% gather("Side","Hipp",-SID) %>%
                   mutate(times=paste0("times",sub(".*(\\d)$","\\1",Side)),
                          Side=sub("^hipp([A-z]+)_T.*","\\1",Side)) %>%
                   select(SID,Side,times,Hipp)
```

Here, the key column `Side` from `gather` have values that are the original `mydata` column names. We use `deployer::mutate` to create a duplicate of this column named `times`. Then we use `sub` with some regex to extract the last digit for the `times` values and to extract either `Left` or `Right` for the `Side` values.

Setting the seed to `123`, your data is:

```
set.seed(123)
mydata <- data.frame(SID=sample(1:150,400, replace=TRUE), hippLeft_T1=sample(6000:8000,400,replace=TRUE), hippRight_T1=sample(6000:8000,400,replace=TRUE),hippLeft_T2=sample(6000:8000,400,replace=TRUE), hippRight_T2=sample(6000:8000,400,replace=TRUE),hippLeft_T3=sample(6000:8000,400,replace=TRUE), hippRight_T3=sample(6000:8000,400,replace=TRUE))
head(mydata)
##  SID hippLeft_T1 hippRight_T1 hippLeft_T2 hippRight_T2 hippLeft_T3 hippRight_T3
##1  44        7973         6941        7718         7279        6319         7465
##2 119        6274         6732        7775         6249        6289         7220
##3  62        7811         6242        6978         6510        6298         6448
##4 133        7153         6094        7436         7641        7029         7833
##5 142        6791         6525        6973         7608        6986         7606
##6   7        6900         7938        7978         6091        7233         6625
```

The result using either the second or third approach is:

```
print(long)
##     SID  Side  times Hipp
##   1  44  Left times1 7973
##   2 119  Left times1 6274
##   3  62  Left times1 7811
##   4 133  Left times1 7153
##   5 142  Left times1 6791
##   6   7  Left times1 6900
## ...
## 401  44 Right times1 6941
## 402 119 Right times1 6732
## 403  62 Right times1 6242
## 404 133 Right times1 6094
## 405 142 Right times1 6525
## 406   7 Right times1 7938
## ...
## 801  44  Left times2 7718
## 802 119  Left times2 7775
## 803  62  Left times2 6978
## 804 133  Left times2 7436
## 805 142  Left times2 6973
## 806   7  Left times2 7978
## ...
##1201  44 Right times2 7279
##1202 119 Right times2 6249
##1203  62 Right times2 6510
##1204 133 Right times2 7641
##1205 142 Right times2 7608
##1206   7 Right times2 6091
## ...
##1601  44  Left times3 6319
##1602 119  Left times3 6289
##1603  62  Left times3 6298
##1604 133  Left times3 7029
##1605 142  Left times3 6986
##1606   7  Left times3 7233
## ...
##2001  44 Right times3 7465
##2002 119 Right times3 7220
##2003  62 Right times3 6448
##2004 133 Right times3 7833
##2005 142 Right times3 7606
##2006   7 Right times3 6625
```

Comment: What column is the `level` in your `mydata`?

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what reshape would give me, but I want to also add a level for side (left/right), not only time. So I actually have a nested design. How do I get that?

Comment: @user6121484: try the edit. The result is not ordered exactly the way you want, but the long format is what you want.

Comment: @user6121484: my second version may be closer to what you want.

Comment: @user6121484: Just to let you know that if you are interested in a third version that has only one call to `gather`, I've updated the answer.